# PayPal Payment form alteration

Tags: html, paypal

I'm working with a client and making some changes to her pricing on her website. She has a PayPal form for the actual purchase process.

Is there a way to change the pricing here without having her go and generate another form? I can see a value in the code for "amount" however there are 6 different items on this form and even when I change that number nothing changes.

```
<div id="order_form">
                    <h3 class="form_title">ORDER FORM</h3>

                    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="business" value="shop@frenchhousenumber.com">
                            <!--<input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="business" value="juliefleming@bigpond.com">-->
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="item_name" value="French House Number">
                            <!--<input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">-->
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="colour" value="blue">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="amount" value="45.00">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="on0" value="Text">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="shipping" value="8.00">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                            <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="https://static.e-junkie.com/sslpic/65354.5118711aaf296c74e60fd8fad8cad7e6.gif">
                            <h4 class="form_subheading">PRICE</h4>
                            <p id="order_price">$55</p>
                            <p class="center">(+ $<span id="order_shipping_price">8</span> shipping)</p>

                            <h4 class="form_subheading">OPTIONS</h4>
                            <label for="order_style">Which style of house plate?</label>
                                <select id="order_style">
                                    <option value="house number">House Number</option>
                                    <option value="house name plate">House Name Plate</option>
                                    <option value="house plate">House Plate</option>
                                </select>
                                <label for="order_text">What text would you like? (Max. <span id="charNum">5</span> char. A - Z, 1 - 9)</label> <input type="text" size="16" name="os0" id="order_text" maxlength="5" onkeypress="return characterCheck(event)" />

                                <label for="order_colour">Which colour?</label>
                                <select id="order_colour">
                                    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                                    <option value="black">Black</option>
                                </select>

                            <label for="order_number">How many would you like to order?</label>
                                <select id="order_number">
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                </select>

                            <label for="order_region">Which region do you want it shipped to?</label>
                                <select id="order_region">
                                    <option value="domestic">Australia, New Zealand</option>
                                    <option value="usa">USA, Canada, Middle East</option>
                                    <option value="rotw">Rest of the World</option>
                                </select>
                            <input type="submit" value="Buy now" class="submit" id ="buynow_submit" name="submit" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Button Clicks', 'e-Commerce', 'Buy Now Button']);" />
                            <br />

                        </form>
                </div>
```

Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want multiple items each with different prices you need to build a cart. If you have one item but you want to let buyer choose how many of it they want, use the "quantity" variable.